The code_verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request for PKCE. error
I'm trying to get access token and refresh token of Microsoft account.
const loginAndGetAuthorizationCode = async () => {
const code_verifier = generateCodeVerifier();
const code_challenge = await generateCodeChallenge(code_verifier);

localStorage.setItem('code_verifier', code_verifier);
localStorage.setItem('code_challenge', code_challenge);
const loginRequest = {
  tenant: "common",
  scopes: ["User.Read", "Mail.Read"],
  response_type: "code",
  responseMode: "query",
  state: code_verifier,
  codeChallenge: code_challenge,
  codeChallengeMethod: "S256",
};


try {
  const loginResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenRedirect(loginRequest);
  console.log("loginResponse => ", loginResponse);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Login failed: ", error);
}
};

This is config
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";

const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "ID", // client ID
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID", // tenant ID
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/dashboard",
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
    }
};

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

await msalInstance.initialize();
// await msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise();

export { msalInstance };

This are utils functions
export function generateCodeVerifier() {


const characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~";
  const array = new Uint8Array(43); // Minimum length of 43
  window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
  return Array.from(array, (b) => characters[b % characters.length]).join("");
}

// Generate the code challenge from the code verifier
export async function generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier: string) {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const data = encoder.encode(codeVerifier);
  const digest = await window.crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", data);

  // Convert Uint8Array to an array using Array.from() before processing
  const base64Digest = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...Array.from(new Uint8Array(digest))))
    .replace(/\+/g, "-")
    .replace(/\//g, "_")
    .replace(/=+$/, "");

  return base64Digest;
}

This is backend
@staticmethod
def get_access_token(code, code_verifier):
    url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{MICROSOFT_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token'

    headers = {}

    print("code => ", code)
    print("code_verifier => ", code_verifier)
    data = {
        'client_id': MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID,
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': MICROSOFT_REDIRECT_URI,
        "code_verifier": code_verifier,
    }
    
    print("code => ", code)
    print("MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID => ", MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID)
    print("MICROSOFT_REDIRECT_URI => ", MICROSOFT_REDIRECT_URI)
    print("MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET => ", MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET)

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    print("response => ", response.json())

    if response.status_code == 200:
        access_token = response.json()['access_token']
        refresh_token = response.json()['refresh_token']
        return access_token, refresh_token
    else:
        return None, None

I'm getting this error response =>  {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'AADSTS501481: The Code_Verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request. Trace ID: 03bb855a-c418-4039-9008-7eec48e91e00 Correlation ID: 6e2d26b8-9a8b-4d06-9326-40ec7659c4a9 Timestamp: 2024-10-21 11:13:56Z', 'error_codes': [501481], 'timestamp': '2024-10-21 11:13:56Z', 'trace_id': '03bb855a-c418-4039-9008-7eec48e91e00', 'correlation_id': '6e2d26b8-9a8b-4d06-9326-40ec7659c4a9'}
